# What standalone software has bleach bypass effect?

Tags: software

I'd like to experiment with bleach bypass, and would like to know what standalone desktop (Windows) software will do it. I would rather buy outright than subscribe to adobe CC.

I read elsewhere I could try Lightroom 6.

Would I need Nik software plugins as well?

Any other options?

Answer (score 2):

There is a free method for experimentation using [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/). It's not as powerful as PS, but for experimentation - it's fantastic.

A quick google search shows quite a few tutorials available. http://www.mora-foto.it/en/tutorials-gimp/bleach-bypass.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try Lightroom by downloading the trial. You can purchase it standalone as well, without the need to do CC on a per month basis.

Nik software is not needed for Lightroom or Bleach Bypass (though it is good software in its own right).

There are thousands of Lightroom presets that you can download, from well known entities to everyone else. There are many more that you can purchase. A simple Google search provides a good tutorial on creating your own Bleach Bypass preset:

http://www.infoparrot.com/how-to-make-bleach-bypass-effect-using-adobe-lightroom/

Otherwise there are many, many available presets. Personal favorites include [On1](https://www.on1.com/free/lightroom-presets/), WoW and [Trey Radcliff](https://store.stuckincustoms.com/lightroom-presets-free-starter-pack), all of which offer free presets and presets for purchase.

Also, Adobe sponsors the Adobe Lightroom Exchange (now called Adobe Add-ons):
https://creative.adobe.com/addons?pp=PSLR